# Cannot turn on WiFi and Bluetooth on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 running on Android 4.4.2. I just bought it 3 months ago. It's not rooted (I don't want root it). I also have "Terminal Emulator" (downloaded from Play Store).

I can't turn on WiFi and Bluetooth. MAC address and Bluetooth address also don't show up on settings. When I press the WiFi button (on the quick settings), it turns green for 3-6 seconds, then it turns back to white again (same as Bluetooth button).

Could someone point me what's the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: What happens when you try to turn them on exactly? Can you describe the steps involved and any errors if applicable?

Comment: [Check Here](http://www.smartmobilephonesolutions.com/content/android-wifi-wont-turn-on) This article may help you.

Comment: Ok,when i press the wifi button(on the status bar),its turn green for 3-6 second then its turn back to white again(Same as bluetooth button)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this very problem on my coworker's tablet. What I did was download the factory image, extracted the modem.bin file, and flashed it via Odin. **No root required and this method will not remove any personal data from your device.** Just need a PC, Odin, a good USB cable, and the device.

Since this question is older, here are two links.

- If your device is running Kitkat (4.X) go [here.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/general/links-stock-galaxy-tab-4-firmware-t3013128)
- If your device is running Lollipop (5.X) go [here.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/general/links-galaxy-tab-4-official-lollipop-5-t3102844)

Both links include the Odin software as well in their forum post.
Samsung USB Windows drivers can be found at the top of this [page.](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117)

Once you have everything downloaded;

- First, install the Samsung USB Drivers if you haven't already.
- Open the factory image with your favorite archive manager, I use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)
- Extract the file, if the extracted file is a tar/tar.md5 file, open it again with an archive manager.
- Look for the `modem.bin` file and extract it to your desktop/folder/etc.
- Once extracted, open up Odin, uncheck F.Reset Time, and hit the "phone" button, I know the device isn't a phone but that's where the modem file goes. Select the `modem.bin` file from where you extracted it.
- Now, make sure your device is powered off. Hold the Volume Down button, the Home button, and press the power button. You should see a screen warning you, that changing your OS could harm your device and etc. Hit Volume Up to put the device into download mode.
- Once the device is in download mode, you can connect the device to the USB cable that's connected to your computer.
- If done right, your Odin screen should look something like this.

  [image]

  except for, in the top right, where it says ID:COM, you should have some info in there.
- Once everything is set up and you are connected, press start and DO NOT DISCONNECT THE DEVICE, until it either reboots on its own or you see PASS! above the ID:COM box. If the device doesn't reboot on its own but you see PASS! in the box above ID:COM, simply hold down the power button to turn off the device. Press it once more to turn it back on.

If everything went according to plan, you should have WiFi and Bluetooth working again.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes it's not hardware failure,* software problem.. like missing driver.. leading to the same problem.. have you try reinstall your tab to the latest firmware?
>   Prepare carefully !!* if you choose to reflash your tab with odin. 
>   google.. and you can find how to flash your tab.
>
> *if you can't find firmware exactly match with your tab, then forget about flashing.

Source: [Jokowi's](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=5917897) Answer in
 this [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/help/wifi-bluetooth-wont-t2805089)